# facebook_scraper only 4 posts when including cookies to get reactions

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

Whenever I try to scrape a particular facebook page and include the cookies.txt file I am getting only 4 posts back. Whenever I remove the file, the scraping continues as usual. Any idea why this might happen? This is my code:

```
with open('aom_fb_2.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8', newline='') as file:
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(["Post_ID", "Time", "Text", "Likes", "Shares", "Live", "Image", "Video"])

    
for post in get_posts('FacebookPage', pages=100, options={"reactions": True}, cookies='cookies.txt'):
   
        images = False
        if(post['images']!=None):
            images = True
        video = False
        if(post['video']!=None):
            video = True
        text = post['text'];
        final_str = ''
        maltese_fonts = ['ż','ħ','ġ','ċ','Ż','Ħ','Ġ','Ċ']
        for char in text:
            if char in string.printable or char in maltese_fonts:
                final_str += char
        post = [post['post_id'], post['time'], final_str, post['likes'], post['shares'], post['is_live'],images, video]
        writer.writerow(post)
```

file.close()

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them? And therefor will try to stop you.

Answer (score 0):

In the [facebook-scraper documentation](https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/) under Optional parameters > options:

Set options={"posts_per_page": 200} to request 200 posts per page. **The default is 4.**

Can you try changing this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).